# dplyr::group_by() with multiple variables but NOT intersection

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

When you `group_by` multiple variables, `dplyr` helpfully finds the intersection of those groups.

For example,

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>%
  summarise(mean(disp))
```

yields

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: cyl [?]

    cyl    am `mean(disp)`
  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1     4     0     135.8667
2     4     1      93.6125
3     6     0     204.5500
4     6     1     155.0000
5     8     0     357.6167
6     8     1     326.0000
```

My question is, is there a way to provide multiple variables, but to summarize *marginally*? I want output like what you get if you do this by hand, variable by variable.

```
df_1 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(est = mean(disp)) %>%
  transmute(group = paste0("cyl_", cyl), est)

df_2 <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(est = mean(disp)) %>%
  transmute(group = paste0("am_", am), est)

bind_rows(df_1, df_2)
```

The above code yields

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  group      est
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 cyl_4 105.1364
2 cyl_6 183.3143
3 cyl_8 353.1000
4  am_0 290.3789
5  am_1 143.5308
```

ideally, the syntax would be something like

```
mtcars %>%
group_by(cyl, am, intersection = FALSE) %>%
summarise(est = mean(disp))
```

Does something like this exist in the `tidyverse`?

(p.s., I get that my `group` variable in the table above isn't tidy in the sense that it contains two variables in one, but I promise for my purpose it's tidy, OK? :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing what you're looking for is the `tidyr` package...

`gather` first duplicates the dataset so that there are n rows for each factor by which grouping will occur; `mutate` then creates the grouping variable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
  gather(col, value, cyl, am) %>% 
  mutate(group = paste(col, value, sep = "_")) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(est = mean(disp))
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Small edit to make more general 
df %>%
    gather(col, value, X1, X2, X3, X4) %>% 
    mutate(group = paste0(col, "_", value))

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` alternative:

```
library(tidyverse)

map(c('cyl', 'am'), 
    ~ mtcars %>% 
      group_by_(.x) %>%
      summarise(est = mean(disp)) %>%
      transmute_(group = lazyeval::interp(~paste0(.x, '_', y), y = as.name(.x)),
                 ~est)) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 2
>   group      est
>   <chr>    <dbl>
> 1 cyl_4 105.1364
> 2 cyl_6 183.3143
> 3 cyl_8 353.1000
> 4  am_0 290.3789
> 5  am_1 143.5308
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**plyr** package is easier.

```
library(plyr)
mtcars %>% 
  ddply(c("cyl", "am"), .fun = function(x) {
    mean(x$disp)
  })
```